# Как получить долготу и широту пикселя на карте из Static API?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-static-maps-api

Я получаю статическую картинку по запросу такого вида

https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?l=map&ll=55%2C55&z=5

То есть мне известны долгота и широта центра картинки и уровень масштабирования.

Также известны размеры картинки (600 x 450 пикселей) и координаты пикселя x, y. Есть ли какой-то метод, чтобы перевести x и y в долготу и широту?

Comment: "Есть ли метод" в смысле готовый метод в АПИ или в смысле можно ли как-то рассчитать?

Comment: @Эникейщик, любой вариант

Comment: Координаты центра известны, масштаб (сколько км в одном пикселе) известен. Остальное арифметика и геометрия 6 класс. Плюс, минус, умножить, разделить. Возможно потребуется поправка на округлосьь Земли, но на небольших территориях можно и пренебречь.

Comment: @Эникейщик, к сожалению, число км (как и градусов) в одном пикселе сильно меняется в зависимости от широты

Comment: Я и говорю, поправка потребуется, если большой регион. Но если, к примеру, масштабная линейка говорит, что 10 км на 20px, то это к чему относится - к верху карты или к низу?

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/map.Converter-docpage/ ?

Comment: Какую задачу вы так хотите решить? Можно перевести [пиксельные координаты](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/theory/concepts/coordinates-docpage/?from=SO#browser_map) в географические. Для этого есть формулы. Пример обратных вычислений есть тут: https://jsfiddle.net/yw86acph/